# Symfony Query Builder: remove results from a request from another requests

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have a first request (I used QueryBuilder but it is a simple findAll()):

```
public function findAllRosters(){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

I want to remove from the results of this first query all results from another query:

```
public function findOtherRosters($user){
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->leftJoin('r.members', 'm')
                ->addSelect('m')
            ->where('m.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user)
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

Is there a simple way? It seems that using a where NOT IN might be the way forward..

**EDIT**
I have tried to follow this exemple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616937/4228086   see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling; I finally found the right Query:

```
public function findOtherRosters($user){
    $q2 = $this->createQueryBuilder('r')
            ->leftJoin('r.members', 'm')
                ->addSelect('m')
            ->where('m.user = :user')
                ->setParameter('user', $user);

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('ro');
    $qb
        ->where('ro not IN (:rosters)')
            ->setParameter('rosters', $q2->getQuery()->getResult())
    ;
    return $qb->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

Hope it can help others with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22616937/3060626)
Here q2 is your second query, the sub result you want to reduce the first result with.

Hope that helps.